# Timer does not get garbage collected

Tags: c#, timer, garbage-collection

When I open the class Cellule.cs, a timer is created, when Cellule.cs is closed, the timer still call the form.

How can I dispose it effectively. This cause a problem because the form Cellules.Cs is opened frequently, and it makes a single call to the DB for each TimeHasChanged();

I already tried to add a Dispose() method in Btimer and setting the timer to null but it's doesn't solve the problem.

```
private BTimer timer;

public Cellules()
{
   timer = new BTimer(30000);
   timer.TheTimeChanged += TimeHasChanged;
}

    protected void TimeHasChanged()
    {
        controller.UpdateTimeMesPieces();
        lblTime.Text = controller.UpdateTimeClock();
    }
```

And heres the timer

```
public class BTimer
{
    private string theTime;
    private Timer timer;

    public BTimer(int interval)
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(Timer_Tick);
        timer.Interval = interval;
        timer.Start();
    }

    public delegate void TimerTickHandler();

    public event TimerTickHandler TheTimeChanged;

    public string TheTime
    {
        get
        {
            return theTime;
        }
        set
        {
            theTime = value;
            OnTheTimeChanged();

        }
    }

    protected void OnTheTimeChanged()
    {
        if (TheTimeChanged != null)
        {
            TheTimeChanged();
        }
    }

    private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TheTime = "Bing";
    }
}
```

Comment: Code doesn't compile: `BTimer` doesn't implement `IDisposable`

Comment: @Blorgbeard Sorry I removed it, it was from my last attempt to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a class contains a member that is disposable that class should implement IDisposable as well

Note: BTimer needs to implement IDisposable.

```
class Cellules : IDisposable
{
   BTimer timer // disposable member

   public void Dispose() // implementing IDisposable
   {
        timer.Dispose();
   }

}
```

then of course when you are done call Dispose on any instances of Cellules

**in response to your EDIT**

you want to implement IDisposable on the BTimer class

```
public class BTimer : IDisposable
{
private string theTime;
private Timer timer; 

 ........     

void Dispose()
{
    timer.Stop();
     timer.Dispose();

}
```

}

something I would add is a Stop method to the BTimer so you don't need to dispose to stop the timer.

Comment: It was from my last attempt to solve it, I edited the post sorry

Answer (score 2):

You *do* need to implement `IDisposable`, and in your `Dispose` method you need to `Dispose` the timer, not just set it to `null.

You should probably disassociate any events form the timer as well (although this may be unnecessary if the timer's `Dispose` method does this):

```
timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;
timer.Dispose();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `BTimer` hasn't implemented IDisposable and you have to deregister your `TheTimeChanged` event after you don't need it any more.